# Unable to delete item from List View using context menu in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, contextmenu

I have custom list view which contains name and username of employees. I am trying to delete any employee. I have use the context menu to delete the employee. 
But I didn't get Id of selected Item in list View.
here is my EmployeeDatabaseHelper class which contains deleteEmployee Method

> **EmployeeDatabaseHelper .java**

```
public void deleteEmployee(String id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    int delId = db.delete(TABLE_NAME_EMPLOYEE, id+" =? ", 
            new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
    db.close();
}
```

Here I am using context menu to delete employee

> **EmployeeFragment.java**

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
    menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,"Edit");
    menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,"Delete");
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle() == "Edit"){
        //ToDo edit employee Code
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle("Delete")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this Employee ?")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dbHelper.deleteEmployee(id);
                //id is not getting here. (My issue)
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).show();

    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is my model class Employee

> **Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {
    public String username;
    public String name;
    public String password;     
}
```

Comment: you need to update the adapter, call notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: ok I'll do that but It is not getting deleted from database.

Comment: @AshishKudale show me how you are setting items in your ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you want to delete item from `ListView` using `onCreateContextMenu`
you can do like this:

```
int currentposition;

listview.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        currentposition = info.position;
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete ");

    }

});
```

Now use this:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    if (item.getTitle() == "Delete ") {
        mArray.remove(currentposition);
        ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But how should I delete the row from database.  `dbhelper.deleteEmployee(id)` still id will get any refence.

Comment: u need to create a column for ids which helps to delete specified item.. then pass this id column with item...

Comment: I didn't get you, please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete ListView Item you should delete this Item from Adapter, that you are using for this ListView.